# Slicing numpy array taking every nth element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have an numpy array of shape *24576x25* and i want to extract 3 array out of it. Where the first array contains the every `1st,4th,7th,10th,...` element
while second array contains `2nd,5,8,11th,...` element and third array with `3rd,6,9,12th,...`
The output array sizes would be *8192x25*.
I was doing the following in **MATLAB**

```
c = reshape(a,1,[]);
x = c(:,1:3:end);
y = c(:,2:3:end);
z = c(:,3:3:end);
```

I have tried `a[:,0::3]` in **python** but this works only if i have array of shape divisible by 3. What can i do?

```
X,Y = np.mgrid[0:24576:1, 0:25:1]
a = X[:,::,3]
b = X[:,1::3]
c = X[:,2::3]
```

does not work either. I need a,b,c.shape = *8192x25*

Comment: `a[:, ::3]` should be ok. Is `a` a [numpy.ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) ?

Comment: @paime doesn't work and yes it is a ndarray

Comment: I need x.shape , y.shape and z.shape = _8192x25_

Comment: If you need 8192x25, then it is `a[0::3]`. @bigbounty answer definitely works.

Comment: it gives me the same size but the elements picking is wrong.. as it should return 0,3,6,9,,... but its giving me 0 1 2 3,...

Answer (score 2):

A simple tweak to your original attempt should yield the results you want:

```
X,Y = np.mgrid[0:24576:1, 0:25:1]
a = X[0::3,:]
b = X[1::3,:]
c = X[2::3,:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(24576*25).reshape((24576,25))
a[::3]
```

`a[::3].shape` gives you `(8192, 25)`

Comment: i did the same, doesn't return 8192x25 x3

Comment: this gives me (8192,25) but not the correct elements as it should give 0,3,6,.. but I am not getting it

Comment: @AR. When you go through the elements of `a[::3]` - it will give you 0,3,6